# Using Reactive Forms to send value from field wrapped in compulsory object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, onesignal

I am trying to send push notifications from an angular app to mobile devices using the one signal API.

The headings and content require a key/value collection for language. So in the form, the input fields are posting a string and the error I receive is this: "headings must be key/value collections by language code", obviously.

I've tried to create an object for the form control and then define the input field as this.title and this.message, but the form control names are not recognized.

What's frustrating is I can see what the problem is, but just don't know the best way to format the form builder properly to accept the right values as a potential object, so something like:

```
headings: {
    "en" : ['', Validators.required]
},
content : {
    "en" : ['', Validators.required]
}
```

//component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.logo = environment.logo;
    this.appID = environment.one_signal.app_id;
    this.icon = environment.one_signal.icon;
    this.segments = environment.one_signal.included_segments;

    this.alertForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      app_id: [this.appID],
      included_segments: [[this.segments]],
      small_icon: [this.icon],
      headings: ['', Validators.required],
      content: ['', Validators.required]
    })
}

onSubmit() {
    if (this.alertForm.invalid) {
      return (this.submitting = false) 
    } 
    this.loading = true;

    const formData = this.alertForm.value;

    this.oneSignalService.sendNotification(formData)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    )
}
```

//form in component.html

```
<form 
  [formGroup]="alertForm"
  *ngIf="alertForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label>Title <span>[Required]</span></label>
  <input 
  type="text" 
  hidden 
  formControlName="app_id" 
  id="app_id">
  <input 
  type="text" 
  formControlName="headings" 
  id="headings">
  <label>Message<span>[Required]</span></label>
  <textarea 
  formControlName="content"
  id="content"></textarea>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send Alert">
</form>
```

//this class

```
export class OneSignal {
    app_id: string;
    included_segments: [string];
    small_icon: string;
    headings: {
        "en": string;
    };
    contents: {
        "en": string
    };
}
```

Has anyone had experience of working with web apps posting to mobile apps/devices in the past with one signal? And, if so, how did they get around this issue? Or do you know the best way to format key-value collections for form builders in angular?

Comment: I don't think you need to change your FormBuilder code. Just format the object you send to `sendNotification`. You can extract the values you need from `formData`.

Comment: @WillAlexander - thanks for the help. So are you suggesting I break down formData into an object and defining the values that way? So formData = { ... }

Comment: `formData` is already an object. You can simply create and return a new object, extracting what you need from the `formData` object (or alternatively, directly from the FormControls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don need to send the data from the form as it is. You can pick what you want from it before you send it to the sendNotification method. 
ex:
      let notification={something1:formData.property1,something2:formData.property2};
     this.oneSignalService.sendNotification(notification);

Or you could define a typescript class with other properties

Comment: Brill, this worked best - built out the form as you described and it's logging out as I need it, thanks.